# Wait until all files are read asynchronously (FileReader) and then run code

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, filereader

I have a page where the user can select a folder to upload files. Before sending the files, I need to read them and check the data. My code is organized as follows:

```
$( '#folder-select' ).on('change', getValidFileList);
var fileList = [];

var getValidFileList = function(event) {

    //Get the selected files
    files  = $( this ).get(0).files;

    for(var i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
        checkFile(files[i]);
    }
    //Do something with the final fileList
    console.log(fileList);
};

var checkFile = function(file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (event) {
        //Here I parse and check the data and if valid append it to fileList
    };
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);

};
```

I would like to take the resulting fileList array to keep processing/displaying the uploaded files. I found that reader.onload() is called asynchronously, so the result of the `console.log(fileList)` after the `for` loop is an empty array (it is executed before the `reader.onload()` is fired). Is there any way to wait until all files are read and appended to fileList?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just keep track of how many files has been processed compared to how many files has been given:

```js
function getValidFileList(files, callback) {

  var count = files.length;              // total number of files
  var fileList = [];                     // accepted files

  //Get the selected files
  for(var i = 0; i < count; i++) {       // invoke readers
    checkFile(files[i]);
  }

  function checkFile(file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(event) {
      var arrayBuffer = this.result;
      //Here I parse and check the data and if valid append it to fileList
      fileList.push(arrayBuffer);        // or the original `file` blob..
      if (!--count) callback(fileList);  // when done, invoke callback
    };
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
  }
};
```

The `--count` will subtract one per reader onload hit. When =0 (or !count) it invokes the callback. Notice that the array order may not be the same as the one from files[n] it this should matter.

Then invoke it like this:

```
$( '#folder-select' ).on('change', function() {
  getValidFileList(this.files, onDone)
});

function onDone(fileList) {
  // continue from here
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This solution worked for me :) the only difference is that I had to pass the callback to `checkFile()` function instead of `getValidFileList()`.

Comment: Thnx. Very amazing though simple trick to use 'count'. I searched for two days for this solution and tried a lot of things and about to try promises,wait, then etc. features. But I have just HTML page & jQuery and no back end. 
For API call I need to send files by AJAX POST call but everything was async, so hitting my head - even is it possible or not? But your answer saved me finally!