# FileReader Javascript API don't submit depending on file format

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, submit, filereader

I have a file input, onclick validates file format and submit depending on file format (valid format is 4 strings delimited by ;).

HTML CODE

```
<input id="loadFile" name="loadFile" type="file"/>
<input id="buttonLoad" type="submit" onclick="return validateLoad();"/>
```

JAVASCRIPT CODE

```
function validateLoad() {
    var inputFile = $("#loadFile");
    var fileReader = new fileReader();
    fileReader.onload = function() {
        var text = fileReader.result;
        var lines = text.split("\n");
        var pattern = new RegExp("\w+;\w+;\w+;\w+");
        if (!pattern.test(lines[0])) {
            alert("Incorrect file format");
            return false;
        }
    }
    fileReader.readAsText(inputFile[0].files[0]);
}
```

The problem is when select a file with bad format submit occurs.

Comment: FileReader is asynchronous. You can't simply return a value, you'd need a callback with the result. This would require a rewrite of the current logic.

Comment: @K3N Ok but, how add a callback to return false if file format is bad?

Comment: @K3N Maybe making button not type="submit" and doing submit only when file format is correct?

Comment: You could also use the "change" event on the input field. When triggered and all files checked and found to be ok, enable the submit button (you would in any case need to do a similar check on server side).

Comment: @K3N OK, I understand both approaches, submit form or enable button only when file format is ok, are similar. I need to know how do it works by callback function. If callback approach isn't possible or is worst I will go with the others, thanks!!!

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42886844/wait-until-all-files-are-read-asynchronously-filereader-and-then-run-code/42887008#42887008) is one approach.